# Почему не срабатывает анимация при сворачивании и разворачивании view?

Tags: java, android, анимация, android-animation, animate

Есть у меня вот такой класс который я использую для анимации сворачивания и разворачивания LinearLayout

```
public class ExpandCollapseAnimation extends Animation
{
private View mView;
private float mTargetHeight;
private boolean mIsExpand = false;
private int mMaxViewHeight = -1;

public ExpandCollapseAnimation(final View iView, final boolean iIsExpand, final int iDuration)
{
    mView = iView;
    mIsExpand = iIsExpand;
    setDuration(iDuration);
}

public ExpandCollapseAnimation(final View iView, final boolean iIsExpand, final int iDuration, final int maxViewHeight)
{
    mView = iView;
    mIsExpand = iIsExpand;
    mMaxViewHeight = maxViewHeight;
    setDuration(iDuration);
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
{
    if (mIsExpand)
    {
        mView.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1 ? (int) mTargetHeight : (int) (mTargetHeight * interpolatedTime);
        mView.requestLayout();
    }
    else
    {
        if (interpolatedTime == 1)
        {
            mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            mView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (mTargetHeight - (int) (mTargetHeight * interpolatedTime));
            mView.requestLayout();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds()
{
    return true;
}

private void setVewVisibility()
{
    if (mIsExpand)
    {
        mView.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
        mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private void setAnimation(final boolean iIsExpand)
{
    mIsExpand = iIsExpand;
    mView.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mTargetHeight = mView.getMeasuredHeight() > mMaxViewHeight ? mMaxViewHeight : mView.getMeasuredHeight();
}

public void reverseAndAnimate()
{
    setAnimation(!mIsExpand);
    setVewVisibility();
    startAnimation();
}

private void startAnimation()
{
    mView.startAnimation(this);
}

public boolean isExpand()
{
    return mIsExpand;
}
}
```

Вот так его инициализирую

```
private void setExpandableViews()
{
    mTitleExpandCollapseAnimation = new ExpandCollapseAnimation(mLlTitle, true, EXPAND_DURATION);
}
```

и вот так применяю

```
private void animateCollapseExpandOfTitle(final boolean iShouldExpand)
{
    if ((iShouldExpand && !mTitleExpandCollapseAnimation.isExpand()) || (!iShouldExpand && mTitleExpandCollapseAnimation.isExpand()))
    {
        mTitleExpandCollapseAnimation.reverseAndAnimate();
    }
}
```

Итог, сам вью элемент действительно сворачивается и разворачивается, но происходит это без анимации... Просто прыгает на экране

Что я забыл?

Спасибо